# Difference between first() and take(1)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am trying to understand the details of `RxJava`.

Intuitively I expected `first()` and `take(1)` to be equal and do the same. However by digging in the source code `first()` is defined as `take(1).single()`.

What is the `single()` here good for? Doesn't `take(1)` already guarantee to output a single item?

Comment: No, the `take()` method returns a collection of items. It must, because you could also write `take(10)`.

Comment: Incidentally, LINQ works exactly the same way, `First()` is essentially `Take(1).Single()`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The difference is that `take(1)` will relay 0..1 items from upstream whereas `first` will relay the very first element or emits an error (NoSuchElementException) if the upstream is empty. Neither of them is blocking.

It is true `first == take(1).single()` where `take(1)` limits the number of upstream items to 1 and `single()` makes sure upstream isn't empty.

This example prints "Done" only

```
Observable.empty().take(1)
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

This example prints "1" followed by "Done":

```
Observable.just(1).take(1)
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

This example also prints "1" followed by "Done":

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3).take(1)
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

This example fails with `NoSuchElementException`

```
Observable.empty().first()
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

This example, again, prints "1" followed by "Done":

```
Observable.just(1).first()
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

This example, again, prints "1" followed by "Done":

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3).first()
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

This example prints a stacktrace of `NoSuchElementException` because the source contained too few elements:

```
Observable.empty().single()
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

This example prints a stacktrace of `IllegalArgumentException` because the source contained too many elements:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3).single()
.subscribe(System.out::println, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace, 
    () -> System.out.println("Done"));
```

Answer (score 5):

The difference in the implementation is driven by the difference in the semantics.  Without any knowledge of the language and its inner workings, consider what these two methods imply.

`first()` implies that it will return exactly one element.  The first element in the collection.

`take(x)` implies that it will return a collection of elements.  The first `x` elements in the collection.

Different semantics demand different names.  And different return values demand different technical implementations.

It's also possible (again, without looking under the hood to get a technical answer), that the two implementations may handle error conditions very differently.  I would personally expect `first()` to throw an exception for an empty collection, since there is no first element.  However, I may reasonably expect `take(x)` to return a collection smaller than the size of `x`, without error, if the initial collection has fewer than `x` elements.  Which *may* lead to returning, without error, an empty collection whenever given an empty collection.

Additionally, as a technical concern, something like `take(x)` is more likely to not actually iterate the underlying collection immediately but rather defer that until something iterates its result.  `first()`, however, needs to iterate and materialize the first element of the underlying collection.